# JSF 2 Payara cluster Cannot serialize session attribute com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps

Tags: jsf, payara

I have an app build with JSF2 + Spring (IoC,Transactions..). The app is running fine on a standalone server. These days I have created a Hazelcast session replicated Payara Server 4.1.2.172 #badassfish (build 235) cluster.
 The session replication is working fine as tested with a cluster test app. Also in my app, the session is replicated as when I move from one node to another the system did not log me out.
The problem is that I have some dialogs that are backed by @ViewScope MBs and I keep receiving messages like :

```
 Cannot serialize session attribute com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps for session xxxx
```

When I receive such a message if I move on the other node the page does not work anymore unless I go to another page and came back to current one.

Any idea how can a avoid this ?

Answer (score 3):

Solved,
The problem was that in my ManagedBeans I had some "services" injected which were not serializable.
To fix that I have marked that members as transient and everything worked as expected.